# DynamoDB - GlobalSecondaryIndex for table conflicts with @DynamoDBIndexHashKey

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, kotlin, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "my-table")
data class SomeJobEntity(
  @DynamoDBHashKey
  var jobId: String? = null,
  @DynamoDBIndexHashKey(globalSecondaryIndexName = "jobStatus_idx")
  var jobStatus: String? = null
)
```

The field 'jobStatus' is annotated with `@DynamoDBIndexHashKey`, which is useful for several reasons (e.g. when reading the code you understand this field has an index and you can query it safely).

In an integration test this table is created with:

```
val createTableRequest = mapper.generateCreateTableRequest(SomeJobEntity::class.java)
                .withTableName(tableName)
                .withAttributeDefinitions(
                        stringAttribute("jobStatus")
                )
                .withGlobalSecondaryIndexes(
                        createGlobalSecondaryIndex("jobStatus_idx", "jobStatus")
                )
                .withProvisionedThroughput(defaultProvisionedThroughput())
```

Both the table and in the `createGlobalSecondaryIndex()` function, a provisioned throughput is defined:

```
ProvisionedThroughput().withReadCapacityUnits(1L).withWriteCapacityUnits(1L)
```

However, defining both this annotation and manually creating the secondary index in the integration test, causes problems when executing the integration test:
`com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AmazonDynamoDBException: Cannot have two attributes with the same name`

So one solution, which works, is to remove the `@DynamoDBIndexHashKey` annotation, and only one secondary index is created in the integration test.

On the other hand, if we really want to use this annotation, and not create the secondary index in the createTableRequest, then it will create the index without the provisioned throughput and you get the error: `com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AmazonDynamoDBException: No provisioned throughput specified for the global secondary index`

So my question is: how can you use the annotation `@DynamoDBIndexHashKey` in a way that successfully creates a secondary index for an integration test?

Comment: This is exactly my case.  My sense is the `@DynamoDBIndexHashKey` annotation is useless in table creation, which means having to "manually" create the GSI, like you do in your `createGlobalSecondaryIndex()` method.

Would be nice if the annotation aided in the table creation too.